# How to set up a MySQL database effectively for large text and html fields

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, database-design, phpmyadmin, tinymce

on my website I will be allowing users to insert text into multiple WYSIWYG(TinyMCE) text fields. Each field has a title which will be used for navigation and for general identification.

**Whats being entered into the database:**
Multiple: text from input (max 255 char)
Multiple: HTML/text from WYSIWYG Editor(no max set)
(could be as many as 20 or so text&textfield's)

**My Question is:** What is a proper way to set up my database to handle the user generated content(should I make 20 columns for text or something other)? And in what form should I send it to the database(just lump it all into an array and send it to database or what)? And should I limit how much text can be in each textfield?

Using: Using phpMyAdmin
Also using CodeIgniter as my php framework

Comment: just use [TEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

Comment: @Erik Yes I am/will but that doesn't answer my question. BTW you shouldn't downvote if you don't care to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left a lot of requirements unstated, so it's hard to be specific.

But here's what I would do if I were working in MySQL.

POST table:

```
 post_id    int      primary key   an id number
 field      int      not null      which of the 20 or so text fields this goes with
 user_id    int      not null fk   the user making the post
 active     tinyint                1 = active   2 = invisible to users (deleted)
 (other identifying data as needed)
 posttime   datetime not null      when the post was first created
 edittime   datetime not null      when the post was most recently changed 
                                    (if never changed, the same as posttime)
 title      varchar                text of the post's title
```

POSTTEXT table

```
 post_id      int       part of primary key
 posttext_id  int       part of primary key 
 posttext     text      part or all of the post's text
 active       tinyint   1 = active   2 = invisible to users (deleted)
```

So, each post will have one row in POST, and zero or more rows in POSTTEXT. Most posts will have only one row in POSTTEXT, but extra long posts may have several. POSTTEXT.post_id is a foreign key pointing back to POST.post_id.  posttext_id is a number that counts up from zero for each distinct post.

Why, you ask, not just put the posttext column in the POST table?  Well, if you are sure you will never need to have your users page through very long posts, you can do this. Your schema will be a lot simpler.  But if you'll have a lot of hundred-thousand-word posts in the system where the user may want to view the nth page of text, then the two-table solution will work better.

This kind of thing will perform much better than a table with multiple text columns for multiple fields.  In RDMS work, you're almost always better off handling multiple similar rows than you are really wide rows with lots of columns.

Comment: Thankyou for your help I believe I understand what you are saying. I will be working to implement tomorrow!

Answer (score 3):

First off, your framework and use of phpmyadmin is irrelevant, but sure, why not use both? They're just preference to you and CI will handle reasonably large scale projects.

That being said, I would suggest you use a relational database in this case. You could scale this however you choose, so for your example let's just assume the relation is specific, like you have an article and many relations to these text fields which are always text fields. By this I mean it is not a massive mixture of any form element type and any variety of lengths and values. In the end you should set it up to do what you need without massive overkill or rancid limitations like adding 20 text fields to your article and not using a relational system.

It would be pretty easy to set up a system like this. I would explain the structure but I assume you understand the concept of relational database architecture. I would provide a link, but honestly just searching the term should provide a vast amount of resources to fill in any confusion.

If you have a specific question I may update this post.

**EDIT**

Believe me, this will not be considered larger scale. It is highly unlikely you would create a single input form that has enough relational fields to cripple performance by this detail alone. Supposing you had even 10 text fields. Your bigger issue would be whether or not tinyMCE or whatever WYSIWYG editor you're using can handle that many instances smoothly. I've never used more than a couple at a time so I don't know myself. I would assume you're going to be safe.

The time required to fetch relational data depends heavily on how you write the queries. I think CI has a database ORM system you can use to help with that so you don't foolishly write a query with insane IN selects nested inside other IN selects... for example. In any case, you would need an absolutely ridiculous amount of relations to even slow down properly written queries. If your form is that big, split it into pages.

Comment: I have worked with a one to many relational database before. Will there be an issue with time to fetch data from the "many table" if each user input is going to generate tens of inputs into the database? I'm a little new at working with larger scale databases.

Comment: I agree with Kai, things start to be "large scale" somewhere around ten million records.

Comment: @KaiQing Thank you you covered all my questions, and I will look into any issues that may come about from having multiple instances of TinyMCE running.